# Using the Element sendkeys(keys.ENTER) in an automated test does not work as expected

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I'm running an automated test, where I need to first type the content into a field and then enter the value in the field and then enter the intermediate button. There is a problem that occurs when this operation is performed twice. Inter will be lost and my test will fail.

I wanted to know the following items in the Selenium 3.6.0 bug?

```
WebElement enterPage = driver.findElement(By.name("inputItem"));
enterPage.clear();
enterPage.sendKeys("5");
enterPage.sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);
```

Meanwhile, the use of Thread and wait does not help.

Comment: I am not able to understand your problem.Can you elaborate more and also mention the error (if any) that you are getting.

Comment: Thus, for example, inside the 1 field is the number of pages. The page number is required to be changed, the code first clears the content inside the field, then the amount of the page is typed and then the Enter button is pressed.
The problem with this is that when the test is run automatically, the Inter button is pressed twice and will not enter the expected page.

Answer (score 0):

Please try below code,

```
WebElement enterPage = driver.findElement(By.name("inputItem"));
enterPage.clear();
enterPage.sendKeys("5");
driver.sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try by usign Actions. See the code below.

```
Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
WebElement enterPage = driver.findElement(By.name("inputItem"));
enterPage.clear();
actions.sendKeys("5").build().perform();
actions.sendKeys(Keys.ENTER).build().perform();
```